# "Embed Your Own JavaScript" not saving in Thesis theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I normally do custom webapps using Symfony2, but I have to integrate into a WordPress install.

I can't seem to get the <kbd>Embed Your Own JavaScript</kbd> input box to save. I've added the script, clicked update a thousand times. No dice.

I've looked at the Network tab on Chrome while clicking update and it's sending the info in the POST variable `thesis_javascript_scripts`. I also scoured the database for anything relating to it, but found  nothing.

Where is this info supposed to be stored? And why it's not being saved?

Comment: @brasofilo Good edit. Thanks, bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.

It's in the `wp_postmeta` table with the appropriate `post_id` with the `meta_key`: thesis_javascript_scripts

When I updated the `meta_value` in phpMyAdmin, it started saving in Wordpress. Very weird.